# Traer datos de la Base de datos según variable ingresada

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, select

Buenas tardes,

Tengo el siguiente problema, espero de su ayuda. Resulta que estoy imprimiendo un documento en PDF, este documento lo imprimo según el RUT que se ingresa en la vista, pero al momento de buscar los datos según el RUT no me resulta. Estoy con Codeigniter 3.

**Controlador:**

```
 $params2 = array('rut_contrato' => $this->input->post('rut') );            
 $rut_id = $this->alumno_modelo->obtenerContrato($params2);

 //preparamos y maquetamos el contenido a crear
 foreach($value as $valor) {
   $html = '';
   $html .= "<h2>CONTRATO DE TRABAJO</h2>";
   $html .= "El siguiente contrato será entre ".$valor->nombres." ".$valor->apellidos. " con RUT " .$valor->idPersona."";
```

**Y el modelo:**

```
    function obtenerContrato($params2)
    {
        $this->db->select('persona');
        $this->db->where('idPersona', $params2);
        $query = $this->db->get('persona', 1)->row();
        return $query->value;
    }
```

De ante mano, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, luego de analizar el código del modelo, y buscar la razón de la siguiente linea:

```
return $query->value;
```

No encontré que -> value devolviera el resultado de una consulta. Al parecer el problema se encuentra ahí ya que luego de buscar en la [Documentación de *Generating Query Results*](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows)  de Codeigniter 3 no encontré que eso devolviera el resultado de la consulta.

En la documentación se pueden apreciar diversos métodos de obtener el resultado de la consulta, y en lo posible separa el get de la obtención del resultado.

```
$query = $this->db->get('persona', 1);
$resultado = $query->row();
return $resultado;
```

o también se puede usar

```
$query = $this->db->get('persona', 1);
$resultado = $query->result_array();
return $resultado;
```

y varios más, estos varían la estructura en la cual se retorna la consulta y depende de ti cual usar de acuerdo a tus necesidades.

Te recomiendo que pruebes imprimiendo con print_r la variable $rut_id en el controlador para que comprendas mejor la estructura de lo que te esta retornando el modelo.

Espero mi respuesta sea útil :)